# PHP Variable in MySQL Query from list explode

Tags: php, mysql

I have a section of code that I can't get to work. the $num variable needs to be passed to the mysql query so it update the latest record with the $num.

The code works when I set $num_d = '1234';

How can I pass the $num variable to the query statement

```
 $test_message ="$full, $t_phone_number, $f_phone_number";

//explode sms message into variables
list($name, $status, $timecode, $latitude, $longitude, $num, $city, $state, $t_phoneb, $t_phone, $f_phone) = explode("," , $test_message);

print_r(explode(',', "$test_message"));

$num_ext = explode(",", $test_message);
$num_d = (string)$num_ext[5];

// Update database table
 mysql_query("UPDATE msg SET timecode_off= '$timecode' WHERE (num= '$num_d') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Please post the results of: `var_dump($test_message)` positioned after line 1 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks to buggy, also three lines doing the same

```
/* Here, what is the $full format? I looks like a string with coma separated */
$test_message ="{$full}, {$t_phone_number}, {$f_phone_number}";

/* Mapping the array without spaces */
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $test_message)));

/* Update database table */
 mysql_query("UPDATE msg SET timecode_off= '{$array[2]}' WHERE (num= '{$array[5]}');") or die (mysql_error());
```

I guess, this code must work, however I don't know the *$full* structure, another think to take care is the ORDER BY restriction, that is for SELECT clause, no for UPDATE clause, probably you need a WHERE

Comment: The $full structure is bbb, UP, 2013-09-18 11:23:56, 111.9999, 123.2345, 1234, san diego, ca, 2131231234,

I tried SELECT MAX(id) but that didn't work.

Comment: I see, probably could be better if you could do a select query before the update, I mean, first at all, get the row that you want to update, and then update it

Comment: Ok so I would update the row in a sub query.

Is 'trim' required? Because part of $full contains items like San Diego or Mexico City

Comment: NO, you need two different queries, one for get the row taht you need to update, and one more to do the update

Comment: That I dont understand the reason on the queries, cause you have and id, but you are not updating that, your are updating based on a 'num', what is the meaning of 'num' field? and what are you looking for  in your query?. Try to understand that before doing the query, cause it looks a litle confussing

Comment: Ok, I will try two queries. What about the trim? 

Each row has two timedate fields timecode_on and timecode_off.
timecode_on is entered when the row is created and timecode_off is NULL.
timecode_off is updated at a later time but it needs to update the latest record and for a particular sensor ie $num='1234' Max(id) or ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1.

Comment: I see, teh trim mapping is just for avoid blank spaces on your strings, and yes, first, you must query your last register, I recommend to you a datetime field instead a max or last id, cause probably make a crossing data, however a datetime ordered could be better, and whe you have it, then just update based on the id of the row gotten

Answer (score 0):

**If** the $test_message is formatted right, you should be able to use `$num` directly like:

`mysql_query("UPDATE msg SET timecode_off= '$timecode' WHERE (num= '$num') LIMIT 1");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$test_message ="$full, $t_phone_number, $f_phone_number";
$num_ext = explode(",", $test_message);
```

The result is:

```
$num_ext[0] = $full;
$num_ext[1] = $t_phone_number;
$num_ext[2] = $f_phone_number; and so on

$num_d = $num_ext[5];
$sql = "UPDATE msg SET timecode_off= '$timecode' WHERE num='$num_d' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
$query = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

Comment: You can't know that `$num_ext[0] == $full` -- what if it had contained comma(s)?

Comment: if you explode this string as he posted above this $num_ext[0] == $full is true                                 $test_message ="$full, $t_phone_number, $f_phone_number";
$num_ext = explode(",", $test_message);

Comment: There is no string he posted above. We'll need to see that to know what's going on.

Comment: There are commas in the $full. That's where these variables come from $name, $status, $timecode, $latitude, $longitude, $num, $city, $state, $t_phoneb

Answer (score 0):

the index "5" in $num_ext is not exists.if you sure that the num_d always in the end of the the exploded array you can use

```
$num_d = (string) end($num_ext);
```

Comment: It's not at the end it's 3 from the end.

Answer (score 0):

First drop the ORDER BY clause. that is for select statement. Next, echo all of your strings before you store them in the database to get an idea what should be stored and what is actually stored. If output does not give you a clue what went wrong then post the output here.

Comment: The reason the ORDER BY clause is there is to select the latest record for $num

Comment: Ok. UPDATE only works on one row at a time. If you need to UPDATE more than one row, you need a looping structure. As suggested above, try a SELECT query before the UPATE to grab the propr id, or alternatively, create the query as a view in the database, per the conditions listed in mySql's docs here: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html), then do your update off of the view.